# How to maintain Server Socket through Activities?

Tags: java, android, sockets

In my application I decided to make a server and client through Sockets (just testing my idea for now).

So I made two **AsyncTasks** (for the server and client) an on my onCreate (depending on user action - as I said I'm just testing, for now just with buttons):

```
new createServer().execute();
```

or

```
new connectClient().execute();
```

Question is, everything works good, but the app where I want to implement my idea has many activities, so the app that is serving the data, when leave the activity where the createServer Async Task is, the client (obviously) loses  the connection.

Is there a way to maintain the server running "all time", and allow the user (with the "server app") to navigate through the app without affecting the connected clients? Because even if everytime I leave an activity I create the Server, the clients will lose connection anyway.

Really appreciate any suggestion.

EDIT: For the purposes of my test application, I need the system to be working only in foreground, no background, so no need of service creation.

Comment: This seems strange - are both the server and client on the phone?  Phone activities that are not on the front are paused, you would have to create a background service thread.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: @sqrfv as I mentioned on answer, let's say I want the server only running on foreground, so no need of services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with correctly managing the lifetime of your server. First you'll have to decide what you want that lifetime to be. Clearly you've figured out that you want it to be broader than just the activity level, but do you want it to run in the background or only when your app is in the foreground? If it is only when in the foreground, you can get away with not creating a service, but instead keeping a reference to a component from your application object. However, if you want to keep your server running even when your app is in the background you do need a Service.

**Update:**

Here's an example of what I meant by "keeping a reference to a component from your application object":

- Create a custom Application class.
- Add a field to hold a reference to your server AsyncTask

  ```
  private AsyncTask mServerTask;
  ```
- Add a method to it to start your server AsyncTask

  ```
   public void startServer() {
       mServerTask = new createServer();
       mServerTask.execute();
   }
  ```
- Probably add another method to stop your server

To start your server from an activity you can now do something like:

```
CustomApplication app = (CustomApplication) getApplication();
app.startServer();
```

Of course you'll want to do more to properly manage the server like making sure you don't start it twice, etc. and you might decide to use threads instead of AsyncTasks but this should give you an idea of how you can have an object with a lifetime beyond that of an activity.

Comment: Yes I already thought on that background using services, or foreground (managing onPause/stop/resume etc) , however still didn't decided. Lets say it will be foreground, how should I proceed to have the server always running without inner app interruptions? Keeping a reference to a component? Can you please clarify?

Comment: Interesting. So, starting the server in the custom application class from an activity, if I execute other Activity the server will keep running?

Comment: Yep. There's only one instance of the application object.